# element is not a member

Tags: c, pic

[image: No se como podría resolver este error, entiendo que el programa espera que mis pines de salida sean valores de lado izquierdo, pero ahí esta la pregunta, ¿Cómo los vuelvo LVALUES?]

Estoy tratando de armar un codificador HDB3, esto con el software C Compiler y proteus, para ello hare uso de un microcontrolador PIC 16f84A, soy principiante y aun tengo algunas dudas sobre el lenguaje, alguien que sepa de CSS o C Compiler que me pueda dar una mano se agradecería bastante.
Cuando cambio los output_a(pin_a2) por PORTA.F2 me sale el error "element is not a member"
Este es mi código

```
    #include <16F84A.h>
#fuses xt, nowdt
#use delay(clock=4M)
#use fast_io(a)

#byte trisa=0x00
#byte porta=0x00
#byte trisb=0xff
#byte portb=0xff

char k;
char memoria[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //bits de entrada 
char p[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //bits de codigo positivos 
char n[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //bits de dodigo negativos 
char sig; 
char numl;//num de unos 
char mod; //para sacar el residuo 4%2=0 3%2=1 
char numc; //numero de ceros 
void main (){
   set_tris_a(0x00); //PUERTO COMO SALIDA D DATOS    0 out y 1 in
   set_tris_b(0xff); // PUERTO COMO ENTRADA DE DATOS EN PARALELO 
   *PORTA=0; 
   delay_us(20); 
   k=0; 
   sig=0; 
   numl=0; 
   numc=0; 
   memoria[0]=pin_b0; // guardando bit por bit 
   memoria[1]=pin_b1; 
   memoria[2]=pin_b2; 
   memoria[3]=pin_b3; 
   memoria[4]=pin_b4; 
   memoria[5]=pin_b5; 
   memoria[6]=pin_b6; 
   memoria[7]=pin_b7; 
   for(k=0;k<8;k++){
     if(memoria[k]==1){ 
       numl=numl+1; //contador de unos 
       numc=0; //se reinicia el contador de ceros 
       mod=numl%2; //para ver si es par o impar 
         if(mod==0){ 
           n[k]=1; sig=0;
           }
      else 
      p[k]=1; sig=1;
      }
//cuando hay un 0 
 else{
  numc=numc+1; 
  if(numc==4){ 
   numc=0; 
     if(mod==0) 
       sig=~sig;
  if(sig==1){
    p[k]=1;
  }  
  else
  {n[k]=1;}
     }
    }
   }
 while (true){ //bucle infinito
   for(k=0;k<8;k++){
   output_a(pin_a2) = memoria[k]; //dato de 8 bits q sale serialmente
   output_a(pin_a0) = p[k]; //para activar pulsos positivos
   output_a(pin_a1) = n[k]; //para activar pulsos negativos 
   delay_ms(1);
   }
  }
 }
```

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.